# Dynamically add ngModels to child elements in angular directive

Tags: angularjs

Have some directive to uncheck previously checked radio in group:

```
(function (angular, $) {
    'use strict';

    var radioGroupDirective = function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelController) {
                var $radios = $element.find('input[type="radio"]');
                $radios.click(function($event) {
                    var $radio = $($event.target);
                    if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true) {
                        $radio.prop('checked', false);
                        $radio.data('waschecked', false);
                        ngModelController.$setViewValue(null);
                    } else {
                        $radio.data('waschecked', true);
                    }
                    $radio.siblings('input[type="radio"]').data('waschecked', false);
                });
            },
        };
    };

    radioGroupDirective.$inject = [];

    angular.module('radio.group', []).directive('radioGroup', radioGroupDirective); 
})(angular, $);
```

Usage:

```
<div radio-group ng-model="fruit">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="fruit" value="Apple"/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="fruit" value="Banana"/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="fruit" value="Mango"/>
</div>
```

It works fine, but I want to remove duplicate code of ngModels in child inputs. Like this:

```
<div radio-group ng-model="fruit">
  <input type="radio" value="Apple"/>
  <input type="radio" value="Banana"/>
  <input type="radio" value="Mango"/>
</div>
```

So I try to add ngModel to all child inputs dynamically at compile function

```
(function (angular, $) {
    'use strict';

    var radioGroupDirective = function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelController) {
                var $radios = $element.find('input[type="radio"]');
                $radios.click(function($event) {
                    var $radio = $($event.target);
                    if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true) {
                        $radio.prop('checked', false);
                        $radio.data('waschecked', false);
                        ngModelController.$setViewValue(null);
                    } else {
                        $radio.data('waschecked', true);
                    }
                    $radio.siblings('input[type="radio"]').data('waschecked', false);
                });
            },
            compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
                var $radios = tElement.find('input[type="radio"]');
                angular.forEach($radios, function(radio) {
                    $(radio).attr('ng-model', tAttrs.ngModel);
                });
                return {
                    pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    },
                    post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                        $compile(iElement)(scope);
                    },
                };
            },
        };
    };

    radioGroupDirective.$inject = ['$compile'];

    angular.module('radio.group', []).directive('radioGroup', radioGroupDirective);

})(angular, $);
```

but it causes an infinite compilation loop and a dead of the browser

Comment: any fiddle will be more clear

Answer (score 1):

You try to compile the entire the directive (radioGroup) again from the link function so it causes an infinite loop.
Instead compile only the inputs:

```
angular.forEach($radios, function(radio) {
    $compile(radio)(scope);
});
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LOFTtnihEUMsbcgBmx6w?p=preview).

Comment: it compiles fine.
but if you add "debugger;" to the head of script fiddle you could see that link function never executes

see forked plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/nGWTcXm9W1C3qO3XWWVx?p=preview

Comment: you can't have both compile and link properties. so only the link function inside the compile run

Comment: thanks a lot. I don`t use compile function a lot and forget about it

Answer (score 1):

Full worked [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nGWTcXm9W1C3qO3XWWVx?p=preview) for this directive (for someone who could find it usefull)

```
var radioGroupDirective = function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            require: 'ngModel',
            compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
                var $radios = tElement.find('input');
                angular.forEach($radios, function(radio) {
                    $(radio).attr('ng-model', tAttrs.ngModel);
                });
                return {
                    pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    },
                    post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                        angular.forEach($radios, function(radio) {
                          $compile(radio)(scope);
                        });
                        $($radios).click(function($event) {
                          var $radio = $($event.target);
                          if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true) {
                              $radio.prop('checked', false);
                              $radio.data('waschecked', false);
                              controller.$setViewValue(null);
                          } else {
                              $radio.data('waschecked', true);
                          }
                          $radio.siblings('input[type="radio"]').data('waschecked', false);
                      });
                    },
                };
            },
        };
    };

radioGroupDirective.$inject = ['$compile'];

angular.module('radio.group', []).directive('radioGroup', radioGroupDirective);
```